# What is Homura's gender?

Tags: sekirei

In *Sekirei*, I am confused with Homura's Gender (Sekirei #06). I just can't seem to find out the logic of it.

Is Homura male or female?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Wikipedia in [List of Sekirei Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Sekirei_characters):

It states under [Homura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Sekirei_characters#Homura):

> Homura (焔, Sekirei #06) was the self-titled "Sekirei Guardian" who protected unwinged Sekirei during the first two stages (this mission was given to him by Takami), usually from Hikari and Hibiki. Prior to being winged, Homura's power and gender were unstable. Even after his body started becoming female (called "feminization" in the manga), Homura continued to think and act as a man....
>    Afterwards, Minato received the power to determine Homura's gender and mentality, but chooses to let Homura remain who he is for now

Comment: i'd assume that he is originally supposed to be a [Bishōnen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bish%C5%8Dnen) character since the main Sekirei Wikipedia page says that Sekirei can also be Bishōnen

Comment: Isn't Bishōnen similar to what Hideyoshi and others are like? But Homura has the ability to genetically change genders.

Comment: @Sukeibe if your talking about Hideyoshi from Baka and Test yeh kinda but his is taken to an extreme where it's given fan service as if he was a girl as a running gag. as the wikipedia article i linked to says *"Bishōnen is also used to describe an anime or manga character who is drawn as if a female, but has male components."*, changing genders would be a plot mechanic to explain why the writer can make them into a woman whenever they want